# CMD: load files with similar names sequentially based on date modified

Tags: batch-file, cmd, copy

I have a folder where every day 3 new files (e.g buy20220716.csv; sell20220716.csv; supply20220716.csv)  are generated and then they are being copied to another folder and loaded. But there could be a situation when files are not generated/ are not available in the source folder, but then after 3 days they will appear, but there would be 9 files (3 files each day  * 3 days )
Need to copy these files from the source folder in the proper order according to the date modified (oldest to newest).numbers in the filenames - date when file was generated:

```
COPY /Y buy20220716.csv %distinationfolder%\File_Buy; 
COPY /Y sell20220716.csv %distinationfolder%\File_sell;
COPY /Y supply20220716.csv %distinationfolder%\File_supply; 

COPY /Y buy20220717.csv %distinationfolder%\File_Buy; 
COPY /Y sell20220717.csv %distinationfolder%\File_sell;
COPY /Y supply20220717.csv %distinationfolder%\File_supply;
```

I made some research, and I guess I can use something like this. also added lines 4-6, per advise but not sure what is it and how it works:

```
::set sourcefolder=C:\Users\Desktop\RER444
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('DIR "%sourcefolder%\buy*.*" /A:-D /O:N /B') DO (SET OldestFile=%%i
ECHO !OldestFile!
SET nm1=!OldestFile:*_=!
SET nm=!nm1:~0,-1!
ECHO !nm!
```

and here is another part, which I am not certain if it is correct:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%J IN ('DIR "!sourcefolder!\*!nm!.*" /A:-D /O:-D /B') DO (ECHO %%J 
    COPY /Y %sourcefolder%\"%%J" "%destinationfolder%\"
echo !sourcefolder!\*!nm!.*
```

but this is not working as expected. maybe there is another (better) approach?
please advise

Comment: why not simply `copy "%source%\buy*" "%destination%\File_Buy\ ` etc?  (btw: `cmd` doesn't use `;` as "command end" - simply remove them)

Comment: simply copy will not work (I guess) because if I have 9 files (for 3 days) there should be 3 sequences: copying the eldest files (say July 16th) "buy", "sell", "supply" to the destination folder then load them one by one. then the same action for the file from the day after (say July 17), then the same action for the newest files buy, sell, supply dated July 18th

Comment: You said that the dates were in the filenames, and showed them too. Why therefore are you trusting modified dates? Surely you should be enumerating the filenames, especially because the dates are in natural sort order.

Comment: I still don't understand why you want/need to copy them "in order". In the end, all of them will be in the same folder, regardless of the order of copy (and clearly distinguishable by the file names).

Comment: Best guess @Stephan, they aren't really copying them, they just decided to tell you they were because they felt that their real task, despite us not knowing who they were or where they work, was incorrectly a matter of security or privacy. _Telling you that they were simply running each CSV, in order, through another process, must have revealed far too much identifying information!_

Comment: @Compo running in order will be difficult if some random files come late by days...